# tcolorbox: It is possible to put breakable boxes behind each other (overlap)?

Tags: tcolorbox

Since breakable boxes in breakables boxes are not possible, as discussed in [Breakable box in breakable box with tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417271/breakable-box-in-breakable-box-with-tcolorbox) and in [the manual of `tcolorbox`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).

So I thought of an alternative: is it possible to put breakable boxes behind each other (overlap)? The box in the background is a little bit larger than the box in the foreground, so it seems to be 'a box in a box', but in reality it are just breakable boxes outside each other. One would expect they break normally?

For example, from the [the manual of `tcolorbox`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf). How can I simulate the 'the box in a box' by overlapping, so that one would expect they break normally?
[image]

Comment: I think you can always play with `overlays` and `borders` to simulate a box inside the other. But with a more accurate description of this problem and even some graphic scheme, it will be easier to understand and answer the question.

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks for your answer! I added an example of the manual of tcolorbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just an idea.

As nested boxes are unbreakable a possible solution when we have only two nested boxes consist in defining the inner box as breakable and draw the outer one with some `overlay` options.

To simulate the inner box, we have to adjust margins with `enlarge ...` option and also define the corresponding `width`. Title, colframe and colback for outer box are fixed in overlay commands. Probably outer box geometry is not correct but I left to you to use better adjusted dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{myfakebreakablebox}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    enhanced, breakable, 
    enlarge top initially by=1cm,
    enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
    enlarge left by=5mm,
    enlarge right by=5mm,
    width=\linewidth-10mm,
    overlay first={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
            ([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)|-([yshift=1cm]frame.north)-|
            ([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
        \node[fill=green!70!black, minimum height=5mm, 
            minimum width=\linewidth, anchor=north] at ([yshift=1cm]frame.north) 
            (outertitle) {};
        \node[text=white, anchor=west] at ([xshift=3mm]outertitle.west) {Outer title};
        },
    overlay middle={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
             ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west);
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
             ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east);
    },
    overlay last={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
             ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)|-([yshift=-5mm]frame.south)
             -|([xshift=5mm]frame.north east);
    }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{myfakebreakablebox}{this is the title}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{myfakebreakablebox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: may I ask, where have you defined the inner box? Where have you defined it to be black?

Comment: @FacebFaceb Not default but initial colors: `colframe= black!75!white`, `colback=black!5!white`. Page 27 in tcolorbox documentation.

Comment: but where is 'colframe = black!75!white, colback = black!5!white' in your code?

Comment: @FacebFaceb . If you dont fix them, these are the used values.

Comment: is it possible that you comment every line/command in your code, so I can know how this has been achieved? Thanks! :)

Comment: @FacebFaceb Every line of my code is explained in [tcolorbox](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) documentation. If you want to use these kind of boxes, it's worth to take a look at it.

Comment: is it possible to put predefined boxed in the place of your black boxes. For example https://imgur.com/BpMotFK

Comment: @FacebFaceb As I told you, what you want is not possible. We can find particular solutions like mine that can be applied to particular cases. What you propose is a different one, therefore you'll have to find the solution or make a new question.

Comment: ok, i will make a new question :)