# various defined breakable boxes inside breakable box using overlapping

Tags: tcolorbox, box

This is follow-up question of my previous question
[tcolorbox: It is possible to put breakable boxes behind each other (overlap)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420406/tcolorbox-it-is-possible-to-put-breakable-boxes-behind-each-other-overlap).

My question: how can I simulate various defined breakable boxes inside a breakable box by overlapping, so they seem to be inside each other? The defined boxes are for example

```
\newtcolorbox{}
```

Example would be
[image]

Comment: Do you know the size of each part in broken boxes?

Comment: @Ignasi it varies depending on the content (user input), but it is measurable i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following with the idea proposed in [tcolorbox: It is possible to put breakable boxes behind each other (overlap)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420406/tcolorbox-it-is-possible-to-put-breakable-boxes-behind-each-other-overlap?noredirect=1&lq=1) this code proposes to declare three kind of boxes: `topbox`, `middlebox` and `bottombox`.

`topbox` must the first in the desired series, it contains and draws the `outer title`. After a `topbox` you can place as much as `middlebox`-es as you want and the series ends with a `bottombox` which will close the false outer tcolorbox.

`middlebox` draws outer lines and enlarges them to join previous `topbox` and following `bottombox`. It shows a wrong behaviour when the middle box is not broken and it's placed to the bottom of a page. I don't know how to solve it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{topbox}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    enhanced, breakable, 
    enlarge top initially by=1cm,
%    enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
    enlarge left by=5mm,
    enlarge right by=5mm,
    width=\linewidth-10mm,
    overlay unbroken and first={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
            ([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)|-([yshift=1cm]frame.north)-|
            ([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
        \node[fill=green!70!black, minimum height=5mm, 
            minimum width=\linewidth, anchor=north] at ([yshift=1cm]frame.north) 
            (outertitle) {};
        \node[text=white, anchor=west] at ([xshift=3mm]outertitle.west) {Outer title};
        },
    overlay middle and last={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
             ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
             ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
    },
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox{middlebox}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    enhanced, breakable, 
%    enlarge top initially by=1cm,
%    enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
    enlarge left by=5mm,
    enlarge right by=5mm,
    width=\linewidth-10mm,
    overlay unbroken={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
             ([shift={(-5mm,5mm)}]frame.north west)--([shift={(-5mm,-5mm)}]frame.south west)
             ([shift={(5mm,5mm)}]frame.north east)--([shift={(5mm,-5mm)}]frame.south east);
        },
    overlay first={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
             ([shift={(-5mm,5mm)}]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
             ([shift={(5mm,5mm)}]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
        },
    overlay middle={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
             ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
             ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
    },
    overlay last={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
             ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([shift={(-5mm,-5mm)}]frame.south west)
             ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([shift={(5mm,-5mm)}]frame.south east);
    },
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox{bottombox}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    enhanced, breakable, 
%    enlarge top initially by=1cm,
    enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
    enlarge left by=5mm,
    enlarge right by=5mm,
    width=\linewidth-10mm,
    overlay unbroken and last={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
             ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)|-([yshift=-5mm]frame.south)
             -|([xshift=5mm]frame.north east);
        },
    overlay first={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
             ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
             ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
        },
    overlay middle={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
             ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
             ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
    },
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{topbox}{this is the title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{topbox}
\begin{middlebox}[colframe=red, colback=pink!10]{this is the title}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{middlebox}
\begin{middlebox}[colframe=brown!70!black, colback=brown!10]{this is the title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{middlebox}
\begin{bottombox}[colframe=blue, colback=cyan!10]{this is the title}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{bottombox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow thanks!! :D how do you know this stuff haha?

Comment: but I already predefined the inner boxes (the black, red, brown, blue boxes in your answer) in a separate \newtcolorbox where I defined frame color, background color etc, so I would like to 'instantiate' them only and without redefining them. Is it possible too?

Comment: @FacebFaceb You have to adapt this solution to your taste. If you read the code (I hope you do it) you'll see that `outer` box is fixed for all of them but all other parmeters can be adapted. In any case you have to decide which box if the first and declare it as `topbox`, which are in the middle and declare as `middlebox` and which one is the last one and declare as `bottombox`.

Comment: @FacebFaceb As I've already explained you, what you want (breakable neste d boxes) is NOT possible, at least with this version of `tcolorbox`.  Therefore these codes are partial solutions that can I think solve your question. Now it's your time to decide if you want to use or not and adapt to the real situation.

Comment: I will try, thanks anyway! Is it possible to reuse parts of your code by \newcommand, if some parts are similar to each other?

Comment: @FacebFaceb I think it's better to use `tcbstyles`, if what you want to reuse is part of a tcolorbox definition.

Comment: it is possible to customize the green title bar to something like page 162 of the manual https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf

Comment: @FacebFaceb   Yes. Read the manual, try it and if you don't succeed, make a new question.