# How to customize title of 'the breakable boxes inside breakable boxes'?

Tags: tcolorbox

This question is a follow-up of [various defined breakable boxes inside breakable box using overlapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426981/various-defined-breakable-boxes-inside-breakable-box-using-overlapping).

How can I integrate the style on page 162 of the [manual](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) to [the breakable boxes inside breakable boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426981/various-defined-breakable-boxes-inside-breakable-box-using-overlapping)? It is more about the location, where to put the code, because whatever I tried the result is the same

Comment: Please show us what you tried in the form of a minimal working example. Also, CTAN don't like you linking to a specific mirror and doing so is fragile anyway. Better use the primary link and let the round robin sort a mirror out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've modified `topbox` tcolorbox to use three parameters (one optional and two mandatory), the second mandatory parameter is the title for the outer box. This title. It doesn't work for long titles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{topbox}[3][]{enhanced,
    before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm,
    colback=black!5,colframe=black!50,boxrule=0.2mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
    boxed title style={frame code={
            \path[fill=tcbcolback!30!black]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
            arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black,right color=tcbcolback!60!black,
            middle color=tcbcolback!80!black]
            ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
            -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            [sharp corners]-- cycle;
        },interior engine=empty,
    },
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title={#2},
    enhanced, breakable, 
    enlarge top initially by=1cm,
    %    enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
    enlarge left by=5mm,
    enlarge right by=5mm,
    width=\linewidth-10mm,
    overlay unbroken and first={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
        ([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)|-([yshift=9mm]frame.north)-|
        ([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
        \coordinate (outernw) at ([shift={(-5mm,1cm)}]frame.north west);
        \node[fill=green!70!black, minimum height=5mm, 
        anchor=north west, text=white, rounded corners] at ([xshift=1cm]outernw) 
        (outertitle) {#3};
        \path[fill=green!30!black]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]outertitle.north west)
            arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]outertitle.north east)
            arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=green!60!black,right color=green!60!black,
            middle color=green!80!black]
            ([xshift=-2mm]outertitle.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]outertitle.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]outertitle.north east)
            -- (outertitle.south east) -- (outertitle.south west)
            -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]outertitle.north west)
            [sharp corners]-- cycle;
        \node[text=white] at (outertitle) {#3};

    },
    overlay middle and last={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
        ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
        ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
    },
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox{middlebox}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    enhanced, breakable, 
    %    enlarge top initially by=1cm,
    %    enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
    enlarge left by=5mm,
    enlarge right by=5mm,
    width=\linewidth-10mm,
    overlay unbroken={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
        ([shift={(-5mm,5mm)}]frame.north west)--([shift={(-5mm,-5mm)}]frame.south west)
        ([shift={(5mm,5mm)}]frame.north east)--([shift={(5mm,-5mm)}]frame.south east);
    },
    overlay first={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
        ([shift={(-5mm,5mm)}]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
        ([shift={(5mm,5mm)}]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
    },
    overlay middle={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
        ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
        ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
    },
    overlay last={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
        ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([shift={(-5mm,-5mm)}]frame.south west)
        ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([shift={(5mm,-5mm)}]frame.south east);
    },
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox{bottombox}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    enhanced, breakable, 
    %    enlarge top initially by=1cm,
    enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
    enlarge left by=5mm,
    enlarge right by=5mm,
    width=\linewidth-10mm,
    overlay unbroken and last={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
        ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)|-([yshift=-5mm]frame.south)
        -|([xshift=5mm]frame.north east);
    },
    overlay first={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm]
        ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
        ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
    },
    overlay middle={
        \draw[green!70!black, line width=.5mm, rounded corners]
        ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south west)
        ([xshift=5mm]frame.north east)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south east);
    },
    #1
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{topbox}{this is the title}{Outer title}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{topbox}
    \begin{middlebox}[colframe=red, colback=pink!10]{this is the title}
        \lipsum[1-5]
    \end{middlebox}
    \begin{middlebox}[colframe=brown!70!black, colback=brown!10]{this is the title}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{middlebox}
    \begin{bottombox}[colframe=blue, colback=cyan!10]{this is the title}
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{bottombox}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note* Previous code has been updated for compatibility with tcolorbox v4.20. If you're using previous versions, rename colors with form `tcbcol...` to older form  `tcbcol@...`.

Comment: Amazing answer. Bottomline for dummies: ``boxed title style={etc.`` and try ``enhanced``, you probably need it.

Comment: @PatrickT Thank you for the compliments. I'm sorry but I don't understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: you're welcome! I spent an hour trying to work out why I wasn't able to have ``\includegraphics`` inside option ``overlay=`` (with a node for positioning) until I realised, by reading your code, that I was missing option ``enhanced``.  :-)

Comment: @PatrickT you're right, I also forgot to add it. ;-)