# How to put text in front of ribbon in tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

Please see page 424 of the [`tcolorbox` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf). How can I put text in front of the ribbon, but 45 degrees rotated?

See example
[image]

Their code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
% \usetikzlibrary{patterns} % preamble
% \tcbuselibrary{skins} % preamble

\begin{document}
\tcbset{frogbox/.style={enhanced,colback=green!10,colframe=green!65!black,
enlarge top by=5.5mm,
overlay={\foreach \x in {2cm,3.5cm} {
\begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=\x]frame.north west)}]
\path[draw=green!65!black,fill=green!10,line width=1mm] (0,0) arc (0:180:5mm);
\path[fill=black] (-0.2,0) arc (0:180:1mm);
\end{scope}}}]}}
\tcbset{ribbon/.style={overlay app={%
\path[fill=blue!75!white,draw=blue,double=white!85!blue,
preaction={opacity=0.6,fill=blue!75!white},
line width=0.1mm,double distance=0.2mm,
pattern=fivepointed stars,pattern color=white!75!blue]
([xshift=-0.2mm,yshift=-1.02cm]frame.north east)
-- ++(-1,1) -- ++(-0.5,0) -- ++(1.5,-1.5) -- cycle;}}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[frogbox,title=My title]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[frogbox,ribbon,title=My title]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.\par
Here, we apply a second overlay.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me insist in [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427990/breakable-box-placement) to one of your previous questions

Comment: Such fragments are not really useful! The text in front of the ribbon should be `MWE` not `text` only ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set a node on an appropriate part of the ribbons `\path` and shift it into the middle of the ribbon. The option `slope` takes care of the rotation. I also added a new option for the ribbon text. You can set a default text, the position is marked tin the source.

The result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
% \usetikzlibrary{patterns} % preamble
% \tcbuselibrary{skins} % preamble

\begin{document}
\tcbset{frogbox/.style={%
    enhanced,
    colback=green!10,
    colframe=green!65!black,
    enlarge top by=5.5mm,
    overlay={\foreach \x in {2cm,3.5cm} {
        \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=\x]frame.north west)}]
            \path[draw=green!65!black,fill=green!10,line width=1mm] (0,0) arc (0:180:5mm);
            \path[fill=black] (-0.2,0) arc (0:180:1mm);
        \end{scope}}}}}

\tcbset{%
ribbon text/.store in=\ribbontext,
ribbon text={}, % <------ set default text here
ribbon/.style={overlay app={%
    \path[%
        fill=blue!75!white,
        draw=blue,
        double=white!85!blue,
        preaction={opacity=0.6,fill=blue!75!white},
        line width=0.1mm,
        double distance=0.2mm,
        pattern=fivepointed stars,
        pattern color=white!75!blue]
        ([xshift=-0.2mm,yshift=-1.02cm]frame.north east) --
            ++(-1,1) --
            ++(-0.5,0) -- node[sloped,yshift=1.76777mm,inner sep=0,node font=\footnotesize] {\ribbontext}
            ++(1.5,-1.5) -- cycle;}}}

\begin{tcolorbox}[frogbox,title=My title]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[frogbox,ribbon,title=My title,ribbon text=Text]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.\par
Here, we apply a second overlay.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```