# Shade text background without affecting mdframeds or tcolorboxes

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox, mdframed

I have some text with `tcolorbox`es interspersed with normal paragraphs. Everything looks lovely so far, even when the `tcolorbox`es have to break across pages (using the `breakable` option).

However, I now need to put a shaded background behind some of the text. The obvious solution would be another `tcolorbox`…but a `tcolorbox` inside a `tcolorbox` can never be `breakable` (as the MWE shows; this is in the documentation also).

What other options do I have to put a shaded box behind a few pages' worth of text? I don't need any of the fancy features of `tcolorbox` (like the rounded corners or title bar or adjusted margins), I just need a nice gray color behind the text. I've tried `mdframed` also, but mixing `mdframed` and `tcolorbox` seems to be discouraged, and it sometimes put breaks in completely wrong places.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
    \lipsum[3-10]
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use an overlaying tikzpicture. Have a look at the questions on this site with "tikz" and "background".

Comment: It's not possible to break nested tcolorboxes, but you could try with something similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427159/1952). There you have three kind of boxes: top, middle and bottom, all breakable which try to emulate a two level nested breakable tcolorbox.