# Nested breakable boxes with line on the left

Tags: page-breaking, boxes

I'm trying to create an environment like `quotation`, but with a line on the left.
I would also like it to support multiple paragraphs, footnotes, and floats (basically you should be able to wrap it around any, or most content and it should just work).

The difficult thing is that I want it to handle **pagebreaks**, even when nested.
From the TeXFAQ entry about [breaking boxes of text](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-breakbox), I know it is possible to do this with the [boites](https://ctan.org/pkg/boites) package, but it breaks floats and footnotes, sadly, so this is not an option for me. There have been [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426981/various-defined-breakable-boxes-inside-breakable-box-using-overlapping) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417271/breakable-box-in-breakable-box-with-tcolorbox?noredirect=1&lq=1) before, but for whole boxes instead of only left lines. I'm not sure if this question might be easier to answer. I am also aware that this is apparently not possible to solve using the `framed`, `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` packages (see the package documentations).

Can this be done?

Example:
[image: Example]

Example code adapted from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018493/vertical-line-with-every-quotation):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newenvironment{quotationb}%
{\begin{leftbar}}%
{\end{leftbar}}

\begin{document}

\begin{quotationb}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{quotationb}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{quotationb}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{quotationb}
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{quotationb}
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{quotationb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer according the exact indications of Manuel comment., arrived after my answer.